# Element is no longer attached to the DOM Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds, when it came out of the loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting the above mentioned for the below code:

1. Opens a page
2. Check if the new month is available
3. Downloads new month ex: Oct
4. Then comes out of loop and should download Sep

But after coming out of loop it is throwing above error message.

Here is the error log:

Download new month
Oct month data downloaded in csv format
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Command duration or timeout: 21 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'Treselle', ip: '192.168.0.123', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Session ID: ecbdefce-d119-43cc-b239-124d9961bf7e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=43.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:178)
    at stack3.main(stack3.java:43)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'Treselle', ip: '192.168.0.123', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .fxdriver.cache.getElementAt(resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9354)
    at .Utils.getElementAt(file:///C:/Users/Ashik/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7980863778031317345webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8978)
    at .WebElement.getElementText(file:///C:/Users/Ashik/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7980863778031317345webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11965)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Ashik/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7980863778031317345webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Ashik/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7980863778031317345webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Ashik/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7980863778031317345webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)

```
driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));
List < WebElement > options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

for (WebElement option: options) {
    if (option.getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)")) {
        System.out.println("old month");
        break;
    } else {
        if (option.getText().contains("Oct")) {
            System.out.println("Download new month");
            WebElement identifier = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));

            Select select1 = new Select(identifier);
            select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)");

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']/tbody/tr/td/*")).click();

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();

            Wait(10000);
            System.out.println("Oct month data downloaded in csv format");
        }
```

Comment: may you attach whole error log?

Comment: Yuck... hard code `Wait`s... The error is telling you that your are trying to access an element that is no longer attached to the DOM, the page either updated the DOM dynamically or it was reloaded

Answer (score 0):

init again after last call in the loop.

```
select = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));
options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

or you can do it in on row

```
options = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

in your code it should look like:

```
driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));
List < WebElement > options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

for (WebElement option: options) {
    if (option.getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)")) {
        System.out.println("old month");
        break;
    } else {
        if (option.getText().contains("Oct")) {
            System.out.println("Download new month");
            WebElement identifier = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));

            Select select1 = new Select(identifier);
            select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)");

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']/tbody/tr/td/*")).click();

            Wait(20000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();

            Wait(10000);
            System.out.println("Oct month data downloaded in csv format");

            options = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        }
}
```

Comment: sorry where should I place above 2 line or 1 line code?

Comment: @user2762008 After your Last println in for look

Comment: sorry same error, i have placed the lines in else part of for loop :(

Comment: and see the code i think you missing one } to close the loop

Comment: no may be here the } the loop is missed but in original code everything is fine. May I know how to set dropdown to a array and from there compare array index to string like array[index]==string

Comment: hi there, above code worked but it is only printing month name and not downloading the sheet, just printing and coming out of loop:

Comment: The old month is: Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
The new month is:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
New Month data downloaded in csv format:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
clicked the next month
The new month is:Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)
clicked the next month
The new month is:Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
No new months are available to download